# Multi components data sharing and html update problem

Tags: angular

I'm passing usersList variable as Input to app-filter and app-table component. In app-filter I'm updating usersList Input and with `filteredDataEventEmmiter` I'm getting updated Input In UsersComponent and with this data I'm updating usersList in UsersComponent. But when I update usesList in app-filter event emmiter app-table component doesn't update, stays with initial value what Im' getting from `getUsers()`. I've checked usersList variable is updated in all components when i'm filtering.

UsersComponent.html

```
  <app-filter
    *ngIf="usersList"
    [data]="usersList"
    (filteredDataEventEmmiter)="getFilteredData($event)">
  </app-filter>

  <app-table *ngIf="usersList" 
    [tableData]="usersList"
    (tableActionEvent)="tableActionEvent($event)">
  </app-table>
```

UsersComponent.ts

```
usersList:any;
.
.
.

getUsers() {
  this.usersService.getAllUsers().subscribe(res => {
    this.usersList = res;
  });
}


getFilteredData(data){
  this.usersList = data
}
```

Comment: Please provide demo with above code in Stackblitz

Comment: Can you attach app-table component code?

Comment: Put in changedetector/detectchanges after updating list. Sounds like angular needs to rebind.